Is the yaw damper on modern airliners safety critical?
Question is inspired by the recent Southwest 737 MAX Dutch Roll incident. The news articles said the crew "regained control", which implies that the aircraft was out of control prior. I did some reading and saw that the 757, 747, and other current airliners are allowed to take off with one yaw damper that's inoperative (out of a total of two). There's even a button to turn it off. Browsing the Reddit threads on the recent Southwest 737 MAX incident, I have heard conflicting reasons for the yaw damper. Some say that the plane will shake itself apart because these jets cannot naturally fly straight without a computer (yaw damper), others say it's just for passenger comfort and isn't a safety item. It would seem rather concerning if Boeing designed a jet that's so inherently unstable that it'll depart from controlled flight without a computer band-aid fixing the instability.

"The news articles said the crew "regained control", which implies that the aircraft was out of control prior." – No, it does not. It implies that the author of the article, who is most likely not an expert in aviation, thought that this wording would sell the most ads.
